# Which UPDATE statement to change my TIMESTAMP only when i change my char to '1'? PHP, mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

This is my table in mysql db:

```
CREATE TABLE admins (
id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
bez varchar(55) DEFAULT 'unknown',
type varchar(7) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'unknown',
exist char NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
tm TIMESTAMP default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;

PRIMARY KEY ('id')
);
```

I want to update my timestamp only when i set exist to '1'.
Not when I change any column.

This is my UPDATE statement:

```
<?php
    if ( isset($_GET["id"]) ) {
        $id = $_GET["id"];
    
        $sql = "UPDATE admins SET exist='1' WHERE id=$id";
        $con->query($sql);
    }
    
    header("location: /index.php");
    exit;
    ?>
```

I tried different ways to combine it with `tm` but it didnt worked!
I tried stuff like this:

```
    if ( isset($_GET["id"]) ) {
        $id = $_GET["id"];

$tm = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

        $sql = "UPDATE admins SET exist='0', tm=$tm WHERE id=$id";
}
```

using `AND` didnt worked.

I tried `ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` in sql but it didnt works for me. Because i want only new tm if exist is '1'.

I tried this in sql:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER trigger_name
    AFTER UPDATE
    ON admins FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF NEW.exists = 1 THEN 
    SET NEW.tm = NOW();
  END IF;
END$$    

DELIMITER ;
```

but i get a sql error message:

```
ERROR 1362 (HY000): Updating of NEW row is not allowed in after trigger
```

so i tried to use BEFORE instead of AFTER but i didnt changed the tm at all.

Do you have any ideas?
What can i do to solve my issue?

**Goal: UPDATE tm when setting exist to '1'**

dont tell me that i am open to sql injections!
Thanks for your help!

Comment: still did not work @ ArtisticPhoenix

Comment: In `SET exist='0', tm=$tm` you'd be changing `tm` when `exist` is set to 0, not 1. Is that behavior what you want? I'd guess you want `UPDATE admins SET  tm= NOW() WHERE id=$id and exist=1`

Comment: First you need to pull the record from the DB to check if `exist` is set to 1 or 0 on the row prior to update.  ( if these are not known ) then you use that to decide on which update to do.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix You don't need to query to check `exist` value. That can be done in the update.

Comment: We may also have mentioned... Your script is open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174). 
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187)
You should always use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) 
in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's instead of concatenating user provided values into the query. Never trust ANY user input!
This will also remove the unescaped character issue like a `'` in a text string.

Comment: ...... @RiggsFolly yes i know this!

Comment: @RiggsFolly this doesnt work `UPDATE admins SET exist='0', tm=tm WHERE id=$id`

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix tm='$tm' isnt working

Comment: @user3783243 yes this is the behavior i want. i dont want it as a where function. Any ideas?

Comment: You don't have `ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` enabled, so the timestamp shouldn't be updated automatically in the first place.

Comment: @Barmar do u think i should active? whats your idea?

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix whats with your deleted answer? It doesnt work but u have any improvments?

Comment: @wemfal - No you should not have ON UPDATE as that will update the timestamp whenever a change to the row is made.  ( which is not what you want ).  Time is a string and so must be quoted in your Query ( this doesn't work ) means nothing to me.

Comment: @wemfal - Your question is too confusing and open to interpretation, I miss Interpreted what it was.  And the real answer doesn't deserve an answer.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix oh what is unclear? So i just have a timestamp that is created when create a new entry in the table. When i set exist to '1' the tm should be updated

Comment: `when create a new entry in the table`  This is not possible to do with an UPDATE one must do an INSERT - this is what is confusing.  What you describe is a created date, which is often a separate field handled exclusively on INSERTs.  If this is what you mean then having a `exists` column to maintain is spurious.  Often one would have both a create and update date field.

Comment: i only want to change when i set exist to '1'. There is nothing with new entry, i only mentioned this because this is the first time the timestamp is generated

Comment: this is the whole point @ArtisticPhoenix 
Goal: UPDATE tm when setting exist to '1'

Comment: Exactly but your ambiguity when using terms like `create a new entry` is very confusing.  This whole discussion in the comments is largely about what you are actually asking.

Comment: so just ignore this as i told you now the goal is to UPDATE tm when setting exist to '1' @ArtisticPhoenix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a trigger will solve this for you.

If we make it a BEFORE UPDATE which is allowed to update the NEW values where an AFTER UPDATE trigger is not, as per your error message, and remove a couple of syntax errors, the trigger might look like this

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER upd_date_if_exists_is_one
    BEFORE UPDATE ON admins FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        IF NEW.`exist` = 1 AND old.`exist` <> 1 THEN 
            SET NEW.tm = NOW();
    END IF;
END$$    
DELIMITER ;
```

If you leave the `tm TIMESTAMP default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;` so that will set the `tm` column when the initial INSERT is done, but not update the `tm` when any subsequent updates are done.

Comment: so i should insert this into my sql? But what does DELIMITER means? Isnt Trigger enough?

Comment: You had that in your example (correctly I may add) so why did you add those

Comment: If the trigger body has more than one statement, you need to use the BEGIN END block. And, you also need to change the default delimiter as shown

Comment: so your answer is working but the problem is: If exist is 1 and i make another UPDATE for example `UPDATE bez` the tm is changed. I guess the tm is changed everytime doing an update statement when exist is value 1

Comment: I want to keep the tm value of the moment changing exist to '1'. Sorry if this was unclear!
It should not be possible to change tm, when it is '1' by changing another column. tm should only be affected by exist. sorry for missunderstanding.

Comment: Thats what this does! It will only change the `tm` if an update query changes the value of `exist` to 1

Comment: Problem is when i do anther UPDATE during exist is 1, it is chaning the tm as well

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE:** Added `PDO` to account for [SQL Injection Attacks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174).

Change your `AFTER UPDATE` trigger above to `BEFORE UPDATE`:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER TR_admins_BU
    BEFORE UPDATE
    ON admins FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF NEW.exist = '1' THEN 
    SET NEW.tm = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
  END IF;
END$$    

DELIMITER ;
```

Declare a constant for `exist` so you can change it when you want. `UPDATE` your query, passing in your `exist` value by your `id`:

```
  <?php

    if (isset($_GET["id"]) ) {
    
    $id = $_GET["id"];
    $exist = '1'; //change this to '0' if you do not want to update the timestamp
    
    try {

        $conn = new PDO('mysql:host='.HOST.';dbname='.DATABASE,USERNAME,PASSWORD); 
        
        $sql = "UPDATE `admins` SET `exist` = :exist WHERE `id` = :id";
            
        $statement = $conn->prepare($sql);
        $statement->bindValue(":exist", $exist);
        $statement->bindValue(":id", $id);
        $statement->execute();

        $conn = null; //Disconnect Connection
            
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }


header("location: /index.php");
exit;
?>
```

See [Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=535bdeb87191d9f530af1ebb77146866).

Comment: It is never a good idea to post an answer with obvious [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174) errors

Comment: I cannot see any real difference between your answer and mine, what is your answer adding to this question?

Comment: same problem like in the other answer: 
If exist is 1 and i make another UPDATE for example UPDATE bez the tm is changed. The tm is changed everytime doing an update statement during exist is value 1

Comment: What does your update statement look like? This cannot be the case.

Comment: u can see in Q @GRIV

Comment: @wemfal that shouldn't be the case. It should only update the row that you're changing if you pass in an exist=1, if you're not passing in exist=1 and updating a different column, you shouldn't have a problem.

Comment: @RiggsFolly apologizes, I made a draft/posted without seeing that somebody else posted a similar answer. Fair point about the SQL injection answers, regardless if the OP says it doesn't matter, it may matter for somebody else one day. I've updated my answer with PDO to account for SQL injections, which should differentiate our answers a bit now. Thanks.